# install python 3.x and resolve spyder locale error

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I've installed python 2.7 previously, but when I tried to delete it and reinstall python 3.x, I realize that my mac 10.6.8 still work on python 2.7. Can some body help me how to remove python 2.7 completely.

Moreover, after install anaconda 1.8.0 for mac 10.6 base on python 2.7, I can't open spyder with message:

```
File "/Users/tieume/anaconda/bin/spyder", line 2, in <module>
    from spyderlib import start_app
  File "/Users/tieume/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from spyderlib.baseconfig import get_conf_path
  File "/Users/tieume/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/baseconfig.py", line 193, in <module>
    _ = get_translation("spyderlib")
  File "/Users/tieume/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/baseconfig.py", line 172, in get_translation
    lang = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
  File "/Users/tieume/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 511, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/tieume/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

and the anaconda launcher always show 'Loading app lists..'

Thanks all.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You're using a very old version of Spyder and that's why this is happening. We solved this problem in Spyder 3.2, released in July/2017.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply remove python 2.7, there is OS stuff that depends on it, however you can install python 3.x along with it.

Regarding the spyder error, to fix it you will have to set these environment variables in your ~/.profile (or ~/.bashrc) manually:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I can only find the  ~/.profile (or ~/.bashrc) but for python in my virtual environment since I deleted files of python 2.7. So adding them in python 3.x doesn't work for spyder for python 2.7